# How can I make polars cut method deal with null correctly?

Tags: python, python-polars

As of current, it seems like pl.cut cannot maintain order and handle missing value (null).
For example, the following code fails, which means it cannot handle null.

```
import polars as pl
s = pl.Series([1, 1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2, None])
pl.cut(s, bins=[2, 4])
```

Another example shows that its output will not maintain the original order of the series.

```
import polars as pl
s = pl.Series([1, 1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 2])
pl.cut(s, bins=[2, 4])

┌─────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│     ┆ break_point ┆ category    │
│ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ f64 ┆ f64         ┆ cat         │
╞═════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 2.0         ┆ (-inf, 2.0] │
│ 1.0 ┆ 2.0         ┆ (-inf, 2.0] │
│ 2.0 ┆ 2.0         ┆ (-inf, 2.0] │
│ 2.0 ┆ 2.0         ┆ (-inf, 2.0] │
│ 3.0 ┆ 4.0         ┆ (2.0, 4.0]  │
│ 4.0 ┆ 4.0         ┆ (2.0, 4.0]  │
│ 5.0 ┆ inf         ┆ (4.0, inf]  │
└─────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

But as of now, it looks like there is a workaround for the order problem ([here](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4286), and the referenced code/function is pasted at the bottom), so my question is **how can I modify the function below to make it handle null correctly, i.e., just return null whenever it encounters null in the input series?**

```
from typing import Optional

import polars as polars

def cut(
    s: polars.internals.series.Series,
    bins: list[float],
    labels: Optional[list[str]] = None,
    break_point_label: str = "break_point",
    category_label: str = "category",
    maintain_order: bool = False,
) -> polars.internals.frame.DataFrame:

    if maintain_order:
        _arg_sort = polars.Series(name="_arg_sort", values=s.argsort())

    result = polars.cut(s, bins, labels, break_point_label, category_label)

    if maintain_order:
        result = (
            result
            .select([
                polars.all(),
                _arg_sort,
            ])
            .sort('_arg_sort')
            .drop('_arg_sort')
        )

    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my solution would be to remove the null values and add them in the end, as you can see below where I adapted your function

```
from typing import Optional
import polars as polars

def cut(
    s: pl.Series,
    bins: list[float],
    labels: Optional[list[str]] = None,
    break_point_label: str = "break_point",
    category_label: str = "category",
    maintain_order: bool = False,
    keep_nulls: bool = False
) -> pl.DataFrame:

    if maintain_order:
        _arg_sort = pl.Series(name="_arg_sort", values=s.argsort())

    s_new = s.drop_nulls()

    with pl.StringCache():
        result = pl.cut(s_new, bins, labels, break_point_label, category_label)

        if keep_nulls:
            nulls = s.len() - s_new.len()
            add_rows = dict((val, [None] * nulls)
                        for val in result.columns)
            add_nulls = pl.DataFrame(add_rows, schema=result.schema)
            result = pl.concat([add_nulls, result])

    if maintain_order:
        result = (
            result
            .select([
                polars.all(),
                _arg_sort,
            ])
            .sort('_arg_sort')
            .drop('_arg_sort')
        )

    return result
```